# What's the point in redirecting output of grep to /dev/null?

Tags: shell-script, grep

Consider this line:

```
${libdir}/bin/licenseTool check "${SERIAL}" "${VERSION}" "${PRODUCT}" ${libdir} | grep '^200' >/dev/null
```

What's the point of looking for the pattern in the output if the result of *that* is thrown away?

And, if a line like that appears as the last thing in a bash script, is its exit value returned to the script's caller, or ignored?  (I'm speculating on whether we can assume this is done for side effects only or returns something to the caller somehow.)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct; the exit status of the last command of the script will be passed to the calling environment. So the answer is that this script will return an exit status 0 if `grep` matched someting in the data, exist status 1 if there was no match, and exit status 2 if some error occurred.

Answer (score 27):

The point of `grep`ping output that is thrown away is that the writer only wants the return status of `grep`. He/She only wants to know whether a pattern matched or not. In your case, the last `grep` checks if the earlier command's output contains any lines start with `200`.

In modern POSIX system, you can do it all with [grep -q](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html#tag_20_55_04) without redirecting to `/dev/null`:

```
... | grep -q '^200'
```

A note that using `grep -q` has a minor side effect, thanks [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%C3%A9phane-chazelas) for pointing out in his comment. `grep -q` exits as soon as it find the first match, if `licenseTool` still writes something after `grep` exited, it will receive a SIGPIPE.

Comment: and `grep -q` uses less CPU

Comment: As these things go, `grep -q` was added relatively recently; lots of scripts still use `> /dev/null` instead because that was all you had back in the Ice Age (that is, 1995).

Comment: Is your first sentence lacking a verb?

Comment: Another disequivalence between "grep -q" and "grep >/dev/null", from the GNU manpage: "However, if the -q or --quiet or --silent is used and a line is selected, the exit status is 0 even if an error occurred."

Comment: if the documentation is correct "the exit status is 0 even if an error occurred"... I think `-q` option does not seem appropriate... because you want it to know about the error by checking the exit status.

Comment: @Mark: After reading POSIX specs and GNU docs again, I think `-q` return 0 when errors occur, but a line must be selected, so I think they are equal.

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith: See my above comment.