# Linux equivalent of windows cmd command

Tags: shell, grep, diff, comm

I'm migrating to Linux, and I need to convert the following Windows `cmd` command:

```
fc file1.txt file2.txt | find /i "no se han encontrado diferencias" > nul && set equal=yes
```

I think `fc` can be replaced by `diff` or `comm`, `find` with `grep`, but I don't how to do the `&&` part, maybe an `if` statement...

Comment: What do the `fc` and `find` commands actually do on Windows, and what's the significance of `set` at the end?  I've never worked with a Windows command line...

Comment: fc is also a Unix/Linux command: See https://www.unix.com/man-page/opensolaris/1/fc/ and compare what it does with https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fc  - likewise, set began as a Unix/Linux command https://www.unix.com/man-page/opensolaris/1/set/ and then was replicated in Windows https://ss64.com/nt/set.html

Comment: @K7AAY Note the `fc` command you link to is a "history manipulation" command, and totally different to the DOS command.  The `set` command in windows hails back to old DOS days, if not further.

Comment: Actually DOS started in 2.20 or whatever (can´t remember) implementing some Unix' isms and not the other way around.

Comment: @Stephen Harris Duly noted. My comment invites the poster to Read The Fine Manual in response to his comment above.

Comment: ` fc` is an historic artefact from 1983 in ksh, when ksh did not yet have a history editor built in. `fc` means "fix command"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Taking a guess as to what those Windows commands do, I'd say the equivalent in a POSIX `sh` script would be:

```
equal=no
cmp -s file1 file2 && equal=yes
```

which would set the `equal` variable to `yes` if the two files can be read and have identical content (byte-to-byte).

As an alternative to `cmp -s`, on some systems including Linux-based ones, you can use `diff -q`. `diff -q` (`q` for *quiet*), contrary to most `cmp -s` (`s` for *silent*) would report an error message if any of the files could not be read. While the GNU implementations of `diff` and `cmp` both first check to see if the two files are paths to the same file (including as hard or symbolic links one of the other) or are of different sizes to save having to read them, the `busybox` implementation of `cmp` does not while `busybox` `diff` does. So on those systems using `busybox`, you may prefer `diff -q` for performance reason.

Comment: Note that, strictly speaking, `fc` is doing a text file comparison rather than a binary one, because the extension isn't one of the ones that signifies binary to it, and the `/b` option is not used.  It's not problematic, but there are pitfalls to be avoided such as converting newlines in either both or neither of the files, and complexities like the `/u` option (for Unicode text files).

Comment: On one line: cmp -s file1 file2 && equal=yes || equal=no

Comment: Note that, strictly speaking, the OP’s commands do not touch the `equal` variable if the files differ.

Answer (score 3):

Your windows command appears to compare two files with the `fc` command, and searches the output for a "no differences" message; if we see that message then set the variable `equal` to `yes`.

The unix command `cmp` can be used to compare files, and it returns zero output if they match, and we can test this directly, so there's no need for a "search output" function.

```
[[ -z "$(cmp file1 file2 2>&1)" ]] && equal=yes
```

Comment: There's no need to even look at the output of `cmp`, or for it to generate output for that matter, as all that is needed is a success/failure result code.

Answer (score 2):

In the `bash` shell, the `&&` operator is a logical-and for process control, allowing a second process to be run if the first process didn't exit with errors. A double pipe (`||`) does similar, but it is an OR statement, and will run if the prior command WASN'T successful.

So given a file named `sample_file` with the contents of:

```
aaa
bbb
123
ccc
ddd
```

The command

```
grep ccc sample_file >/dev/null && echo found || echo not found
```

Will echo "found" and this one -

```
grep cow sample_file >/dev/null && echo found || echo not found
```

Will echo "not found"

Simply replace the echo statements with your variable assignment.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198128/ for what one can then do if one has a POSIX-conformant `grep` and isn't worried about older `grep` programs.

Comment: @JdeBP, with those ancient non-standard `grep` implementations that don't support `-q`, `grep -l cow sample_file > /dev/null` would be a close equivalent as it would also stop at the first match.